# How to encapsulate PHP subdirectories in Apache?

Tags: php, htaccess

We have separate WordPress installation directories in one webspace on the same User. (Wordpress_01, Wordpress_02...)

It is possible to block PHP script Actions between the directories? (is the best method using .htaccess?)

A few weeks ago 1 WordPress installation was infected and the script scans and changed files in all other WordPress installations on the upper/root directory.

Comment: Welcome to the community. I'm using you're running PHP with Apache. You're using vHosts?

Comment: Thanks, i dont know. Its shared Hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible even if this configuration isn't all that secure. You really should have a different user for each installation (or, nowadays, separate containers).

But you can tighten each installation using the `open_basedir` security restriction. Keep in mind that this can be circumvented in some instances, as it only affects Apache and PHP and *some* other functions such as MySQL SAVE DATA INFILE, not e.g. all commands that might be issued through `system` or `shell_exec` etc..